# c# http request as short as possible

Tags: c#, .net, c#-3.0

What is the simplest way to make an HTTP request? I don't need to read the answer, I just want to send a GET request to an url as simple as possible. I'm using .NET framework 3.5. Waiting for a response is not required either.

At this moment I'm using the following, but I'm wondering if there is a better (shorter/doesn't wait for a response) way.

```
((HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://foo.bar/?q=test")).GetResponse();
```

Comment: Encapsulate the code to do the http request into a method and use the method instead.

Comment: How do you know it's been sent if you don't have a response?

Comment: @DavidG its a local server I also wrote on the same network, I monitor it from on there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Waiting for a response is not required either.

Be ***very careful*** with that requirement.  People seem to *love* to "fire and forget" for performance reasons right up until there's something wrong with the system.  Then they find that the "forget" part means that the system was explicitly designed *not* to handle error conditions.

---

Now, having said that, since you're using 3.0 and don't have the luxury of `async` or the TPL, you may simply be looking at starting a thread to do the work so that the invoked code returns immediately.  (The "don't wait for a response" part.)  Combine this with wrapping it in a handy method and you have the "short" part as well.

Maybe something like this:

```
public static void SendRequest(string url)
{
    var thread = new Thread(ThisClass.SendRequest));
    thread.Start(url);
    // maybe do something to monitor the thread object?
}

private static void SendRequest(object url)
{
    var response = ((HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(string.Format("{0}", url))).GetResponse();
    // You have a response, might as well examine it for success/failure
}
```

So consuming code would simply call:

```
ThisClass.SendRequest("http://foo.bar/?q=test");
```

The idea here is that *consuming code* doesn't need to wait for a response, but *the thread* can wait for the response and handle it accordingly.  Even if "handling" it simply means doing nothing for success conditions.